# Multiple types for f in this picture?

Tags: haskell, gadt

[image]
https://youtu.be/brE_dyedGm0?t=1362

```hs
data T a where
  T1 :: Bool -> T Bool
  T2 :: T a

f x y = case x of
  T1 x -> True
  T2   -> y
```

Simon is saying that `f` could be typed as `T a -> a -> a`, but I would think the return value MUST be a Bool since that is an explicit result in a branch of the case expression. This is in regards to Haskell GADTs. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of the whole point of GADTs. Matching on a constructor can cause additional type information to come into scope.

Let's look at what happens when GHC checks the following definition:

```
f :: T a -> a -> a
f x y = case x of
    T1 _ -> True
    T2   -> y
```

Let's look at the `T2` case first, just to get it out of the way. `y` and the result have the same type, and `T2` is polymorphic, so you can declare its type is also `T a`. All good.

Then comes the trickier case. Note that I removed the binding of the name `x` inside the `case` as the shadowing might be confusing, the inner value isn't used, and it doesn't change anything in the explanation. When you match on a GADT constructor like `T1`, one that explicitly sets a type variable, it introduces additional constraints inside that branch which add that type information. In this case, matching on `T1` introduces a `(a ~ Bool)` constraint. This type equality says that `a` and `Bool` match each other. Therefore the literal `True` with type `Bool` matches the `a` written in the type signature. `y` isn't used, so the branch is consistent with `T a -> a -> a`.

So it all matches up. `T a -> a -> a` is a valid type for that definition. But as Simon is saying, it's ambiguous. `T a -> Bool -> Bool` is also a valid type for that definition. Neither one is more general than the other, so the definition doesn't have a principle type. So the definition is rejected unless a type is provided, because inference cannot pick a single most-correct type for it.

Comment: so how I annotate the function comes down to how I want it to be used? like if i go with `T a -> Bool -> Bool` then the compiler won't allow `f T2 1` and that's basically the difference?

Comment: @nick Yes. When you're using a GADT, you tend to have something in mind that means you know which case you want. It's only in these very silly example cases that it's hard for you to pick a type, as the code's author.

Answer (score 2):

A value of type `T a` with `a` different from `Bool` can never have the form `T1 x` (since that has only type `T Bool`).

Hence, in such case, the `T1 x` branch in the `case` becomes inaccessible and can be ignored during type checking/inference.

More concretely: GADTs allow the type checker to assume type-level equations during pattern matching, and exploit such equations later on. When checking

```
f :: T a -> a -> a
f x y = case x of
  T1 x -> True
  T2   -> y
```

the type checker performs the following reasoning:

```
f :: T a -> a -> a
f x y = case x of
  T1 x -> -- assume: a ~ Bool
          True  -- has type Bool, hence it has also type a
  T2   -> -- assume: a~a  (pointless)
          y     -- has type a
```

Thanks to GADTs, both branches of the case have type `a`, hence the whole case expression has type `a` and the function definition type checks.

More generally, when `x :: T A` and the GADT constructor was defined as `K :: ... -> T B` then, when type checking we can make the following assumption:

```
case x of
  K ... ->  -- assume: A ~ B
```

Note that `A` and `B` can be types involving type variables (as in `a~Bool` above), so that allows one obtain useful information about them and exploit it later on.